# How to stop TensorFlow session from stealing stdout handle

Tags: tensorflow, session, logging

Before starting TensorFlow session, I can print out texts normally with `print` function. However, after TensorFlow session starts, I have to use `tf.logging.info` to log out.

This is the only log function which works after session starts:

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO);
log = tf.logging.info;
```

It seems TensorFlow session is stealing stdout. How to keep the original stdout at its place so `print` function works as usual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems there's no way to stop TensorFlow from stealing stdout handle when using Estimator. When switching to raw tensor math, or Keras. I can handle the stdout using `print` normally just like when coding with Python raw code.